# Usestate hook is not fully updating. In react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a timer component in React and facing a peculiar issue. The timer is visually updating correctly in the browser, showing the incrementation of seconds, minutes, and hours. However, when I attempt to log the value of `second` to the console from within my interval function, it consistently shows as 0. This inconsistency is puzzling because the visual representation in the DOM indicates the timer is functioning as expected, yet the console log suggests the `second` variable isn't updating in the way I anticipated. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```js
export const Timer = () =>{
  const [hour, setHour] = useState(0)
  const [minute, setMinute] = useState(0)
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(0)

  const startConting = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(second > 60){
        if(minute > 60){
          // Add hour, the programe doesn't 
          //support days
          if(hour <=24) {
            setHour((prev) => prev + 1)
            setMinute(0)
            setSecond(0)
          }else{
            // Add minute
            setMinute(prev => prev + 1)
            setSecond(0)
          }
        }
      }else{
        // Add second
        setSecond(prev => prev + 1)
      }
      console.log(second)
    }, 1000);
  }

  return(
    <>
      <div className="conter ">
        <span className="hours  time">
          {hour >= 10 ? hour : "0"+ hour }
        </span>
        <span className="time"> : </span> 
        <span className="munites time">
          {minute >= 10 ? minute : "0"+ minute }
        </span>
        <span className="time"> : </span>
        <span className="seconds time">
          {second >= 10 ? second : "0" + second }
        </span>
        <button onClick= {startConting}>
            Start
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Despite the timer updating in the DOM, the `second` variable logged within the `startConting` function doesn't reflect these changes, remaining at 0 even as the timer advances. This inconsistency makes it challenging to transition the timer from seconds to minutes, and so on. Additionally, I have implemented a method to clear the interval correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Additionally... *"There is another code for clearing the interval and is working correctly."* - The code you're not showing may be working as you expect, but that doesn't mean it's not affecting this functionality. The interval callback function will have a closure around the values it's using, so those values won't change. You may want to start this interval in a `useEffect` operation, clearing the interval from that effect, and include the state values being used as dependencies for that effect.

Comment: `timer` isn't a valid React component, React component names are capitalized. Where are you calling the start function? This doesn't appear to be a complete [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps the issue arises because the interval callback captures the initial `second` state, leading to it not updating within the callback. Use functional updates for state to always work with current values. Adjust your logic so that when `second` reaches 59, you reset seconds and increment minutes, and do the same for hours when `minute` reaches 59. This approach ensures your timer accurately transitions from seconds to minutes, and minutes to hours, fixing the problem of `second` always logging as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using useState, you should use *[useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)*:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (second >= 59) {
        if (minute >= 59) {
          setHour((prev) => prev + 1);
          setMinute(0);
        } else {
          setMinute((prev) => prev + 1);
        }
        setSecond(0);
      } else {
        setSecond((prev) => prev + 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [second, minute, hour]);
```

This is the recommended way to handle side effects in functional components, including setting up intervals.

Additional note: Just in case you didn't import them:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: The `useEffect` isn't the only way to do side-effects, the `startConting` function in OP's code is perfectly valid for issuing a side-effect in response to a DOM event, e.g. clicking a button.

Comment: The idea was to start conting ( by clicking a start button), and then It would start counting. It is counting well and I am able to see the change in the DOM. But inside the startcounting function the value of second is not changing. Is always 0, yet in the DOM is changing well.